# I'm Trying to install rtl8814au drivers fairly new to linux

Tags: wireless, realtek, additional-drivers

I have an rtl8814au WiFi chipset that I am trying to get to work with Linux:

1. I have tried downloading the file (.zip) then
2. Going in the terminal and changing directory the one that contains the file and then
3. `./ (filename)` to run.

   - I get permission denied error so
4. I tried `chmod +x (filename)` then `./ (filename)` again and got the error below.  I have almost no experience with Linux other than installing it and update and upgrade so any help is greatly appreciated.

   ```
   root@Graybox:/home/kryas/Downloads#  ./rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip
   ./rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
   ./rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip: line 2: $'\273\201QI\030': command not found
   ./rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
   ./rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip: line 8: ��QIf����G rtl8814AU-driver- 4.3.21/LICENSEUT2[X�\[s�ȱ~�:?bJy�TE�k�$'�Nm%Q�RH�^�$�"b`0�d����e�/�ŕ�- �����ח��������7u��'���4~��\��$��<K�.]��;�����- �lg~'��oGK�W�*u%��{���y���b�U����{�������a�1���J���г�sg����{к*��2}^W������eoJ���XU�I��MQ�ˤ�����>����b����N���IW���dEQ��e�+"�y`�O޿���������������+wK�ݺr�V�[ڪ�
                                           ph�|i����t^W��+��fC_��[�l�ƛ*2�,�b�Y<o�$N�g�VD>/*�dY���}s����%�y������ޮ��n���T迥��s.�V�7|���쮨K��ņ��k~�`^�˪o��ȫ2�`��Z��e�z��4�\�����r�pF����R��    <�}�G6ħ��-�lKг�Q�<z[{�M�$�zsB���6�)��,>
   O���9���i�q��)m�lnQ@o ���aߥ�2)w�l:�}��e��ڧ���$����0âW�=N�(X���]n_!حK��4X���}E�n�ʒ�  ��H9Ͷ����=����^|�IEZa�ɋ�p�����g�Uw�gVÆ5x��6]i����E�Y'

    root@Graybox:/home/kryas/Downloads# cd /home/kryas/Downloads/rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip
   ```

Comment: please add link of the download...

Comment: The most recent version of the drivers that I could find and worked for me were [those from aircrack-ng](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au). There are simple instructions in the README. Worked for me using Asus AC68 dongle on Ubuntu 16.04 using kernel 4.15.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you get a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tether or whatever means possible. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU.git
cd rtl8814AU
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot with the device inserted and your wireless should be working.

Reference: https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU

Comment: Unfortunatly this driver does not accept monitor mode: __command failed: Operation not supported (-95)__

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Worked like a charm! Same speed as for WIndows 10.

Comment: I had to get [zebulon2's fork](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au) to get it to compile on Linux 4.13.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first extract the `zip` file and then run `make` and `make install` but the previous driver should be *removed first*.

The steps should be:

- Download the driver and place it on your Desktop
- Then, in the `terminal` application, do the following (in blue)...

  - `cd ~/Desktop` # change to the Desktop directory
  - `unzip rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21.zip` # uncompress the .zip file
  - `cd rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21` # change directory to the unzipped files
  - `make` # compile the driver
  - `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8814au` # remove any currently installed driver
  - `sudo make install` # install the new driver
  - `sudo modprobe -v rtl8814au` # load the new driver
- Done! Plug in your wireless adapter.

Comment: Good job George. I'd add step 1.1 "In `terminal`..., and I'd change step 2/4 to "Change directory to...". `cd ~/Desktop/rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21` etc. +1 vote

Comment: @heynnema, I don't seem to able to get the `1.1` addition your suggesting please could you be kind enough to make the changes.

Comment: Does that look OK to you? ps: this assumes the non-dkms version

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys i cant really tell who was right as i kept getting errors but i decided to plig it in and it work... i wonder if ubuntu da the and just added the driver?

Comment: Most probably a glitch that corrected it self, great its ok now...

Answer (score 2):

I took sbosshardt's work as foundation, merged changes from other forks and applied some other tweaks in my fork here: https://github.com/nazar-pc/RTL8814AU

Readme contains easy to follow instructions on how to install or remove the driver. Currently this is the most up to date working driver I know, it should work on modern kernels up to 4.14-rc2 (probaly even further).

Comment: Unfortunatly this driver does not accept monitor mode: __command failed: Operation not supported (-95)__

Comment: Yeah, there is no single perfect driver for any use case yet. For monitor mode I'd suggest a fork by aircrack-ng developer: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Comment: @nazar-pc I am trying to use your driver, but I only get 0-2MB/s this is on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Do we need to tell it to use USB3 or is that part of the driver?

Comment: This is with DWA-192, in the same room as my router, my windows pc got 300+ Mbit in a room futher away. And it seems to use USB3 according to this "Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8814au, 5000M"

Comment: I'm not owning my own device for a long time now, can't suggest anything specific. But I was getting hundreds of Mbps back then for sure.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the post! Could you please tell, if this solution works with the latest LTS version of Ubuntu? I'm thinking about buying this device.