# Install rtl8814AU driver on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I tried installing the rtl8814AU driver for my TP Link T9UH wifi adapter on Ubuntu 16.04.01 (kernel version: 4.13.0.37).
I used https://github.com/mathew19/rtl8814AU and used the answer of George Udosen on this ([I'm Trying to install rtl8814au drivers fairly new to linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884591/im-trying-to-install-rtl8814au-drivers-fairly-new-to-linux)) topic. 
At first it worked, even though I wasn't able to sudo modprobe -v rtl8814au. The response when I entered this was: 'modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8814au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic'.
I was able to go on the internet and install updates and everything, but after rebooting, nothing worked anymore. 
I don't really have a lot of experience on Linux, and I really don't know what to do now.
Can anyone help me?

The results of modinfo 8814au:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAp6H.jpg

When I enter dkms status, it gives me:
rtl8192eu,  4.4: added
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 8814au` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: No, not rtl8814au; but 8814au. It makes a difference.

Comment: What kernel? `uname -a` in terminal, edit the question to add results

Comment: When I enter sudo modprobe -v 8814au, it says: 'insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/8814au.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8814au': Exec format error

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `modinfo 8814au | grep "file|vermagic'`

Comment: It doesn't give me any results, for some reason it blocks at the grep "file|vermagic'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason dkms built on the old kernel rather than the new one, in terminal do

```
sudo dkms remove 8814au/4.3.21 -k 4.13.0-37-generic
sudo dkms install 8814au/4.3.21
```

Reboot and it should work

To fix this for newer kernels

```
sudo apt-get install gksudo
gksudo gedit /usr/src/8814au-4.3.21/dkms.conf
```

Change the first line from `MAKE="'make'"` to `MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"`
Save and exit gedit and it should work correctly in future kernel updates

Comment: When I try sudo dkms remove 8814au/4.3.21 -k 4.13.0-37-generic, it says: Error! There are no instances of module: 8814au
4.3.21 located in the DKMS tree

Comment: And when I try to sudo dkms install 8814au/4.3.21 it says:
Error! Could not find module source directory. 
Directory: /usr/src/8814au-4.3.21 does not exist

Comment: So `dkms status` has no result containing 8814?

Comment: dkms status gives me:  
rtl8192eu, 4.4: added  
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)  
rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: So apparently the problem was that it should be rtl8814au instead of 8814au. It worked now!
Thank you very much!

Comment: So, now it doesn't work anymore. My computer wanted to update something, then it said there was some kind of software problem and after that, my wifi adapter didn't work anymore. Dkms status gives me: rtl8814au, 4.3.21, 4.13.0-38-generic, x68_64: installed

Comment: What about `modinfo 8814au | egrep 'filename|vermagic'`

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. But it worked again after I deleted everything that was shown when I entered dkms status and reinstalled using ```sudo dkms install 8814au/4.3.21.``` But every time after something is updated on my computer, the same thing happens again. And then I see that there is a difference again between the built and installed module, so I'm guessing my kernel is updating and the driver doesn't update with it. Is there a way to change this, so I don't have to remove and reinstall it everytime?

Comment: @Sjoukje___ Did you edit the dkms.conf file?  That is what makes the difference

Comment: I had this same problem. But instead of building with the old kernel, dkms gave me a message of "Great news" about the module being identical to the one "installed" so it was not going to substitute it with the new one, and saying to use --force if I wanted to. I reinstalled the module with --force and it worked. sudo dkms remove mt7610u_sta/1.0 --all && sudo dkms install --force mt7610u_sta/1.0