# Asus USB-AC68 [0b05:1817] drivers? 802.11ac support?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, asus, realtek-wireless

I was following instructions on installing drivers for the USB-AC68, see this link: [Asus USB-AC68 [0b05:1817] drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879187/asus-usb-ac68-0b051817-drivers)

Everything went well, however when looking at the cababilities with

```
iw list
```

any mentioning of VHT modes or even monitor mode is missing.

Is this driver meant to support 802.11ac?

Comment: What is the channel speed displayed?

Comment: from the top of my head I remember that iw list showed supported MCS up to 23, which is HT 3 stream. Will check tomorrow what is looks like when a STA is associated.

Comment: when running the USB-AC68 as STA, checking in the AP I can see that it is associated as  IEEE80211_MODE_11AC_VHT40.
I guess this means that the driver offers 802.11ac support.

Do you think there will be updates to the driver, offering more control, including monitor mode?