# Support for TP-Link Archer T9UH on 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I don't get my USB WiFi working. 
The TP-Link Archer T9UH is using the Realtek RTL8814AU chip set. 
Found [here](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T9UH). The driver link on this side points to a driver which is only for older kernels < 4.4.

Searching around I found some drivers for this chip set. The last one I tried is [this](https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU) one.

The installation of the modules works lsmod shows it with usage 0. 
lsusb shows

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2357:0106
```

Any ideas to get the WiFi working?

Comment: I suggest that you try @Pilot6 's answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/879187/asus-usb-ac68-0b051817-drivers/879258#879258

Comment: With this I get the following from dmesg [ 1348.317361] 8814au: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 1348.318100] 8814au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel -  but no WiFi

Comment: After reboot and manual modprobe I got the following in dmesg: `[  110.968228] 8814au: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  110.968686] 8814au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  110.970796] RTL871X: module init start
[  110.970797] RTL871X: rtl8814au v4.3.21_17997.20160531
[  110.970823] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8814au
[  110.970824] RTL871X: module init ret=0` but still no WiFi

Comment: Let's see: `dmesg | grep -e 8814 -e RTL` and also:`rfkill list all` and also:`iwconfig`

Comment: This fork ist the solution: https://github.com/ScrambledAuroras/rtl8814AU/commit/44134fa948510afa9da37471fd33d87815a59742 It will add the device id.

Comment: Hmm, I need to do a `sudo modprobe 8814au` after each reboot. Any ideas?

Comment: You also need to disable `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

This [fork](https://github.com/ScrambledAuroras/rtl8814AU/commit/44134fa948510afa9da37471fd33d87815a59742) is the solution - it will add the TP-Link device id. 
After install the module I needed to insert the `8814au` in `/etc/modules` to get the module loaded at boot time.

Comment: Can give some feedback on how well this device performs on Linux or Windows? MTR logs from full load on wifi for some time or something? Device is quite expensive and 5GHz adapters are few on Linux I hope you can share this info you're one of the only mentions on Google using this adapter in Linux :) Thanks!

Comment: Using https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU worked for me. The fork referred to in the answer was merged into here at some point.

Comment: We are using using this device with Linux. The performance is exellent.

Comment: I had to get [zebulon2's fork](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au) to get it to compile on Linux 4.13.

Answer (score 1):

This fork: https://github.com/mathew19/rtl8814AU, will work with the latest 17.10 kernel

Answer (score 0):

This fork worked for me on Ubuntu and also on my Raspberry Pi 4:
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au