# TP Link t9uh driver not working

Tags: networking, drivers, make, dkms, tp-link

I am trying to install my TP-link T9UH wifi adapter. I have tried to official driver and the version from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902643/support-for-tp-link-archer-t9uh-on-16-04-lts) but it is not working. I downloaded the driver from the [repository listed in the previous post](https://github.com/ScrambledAuroras/rtl8814AU) and ran the following command from inside the directory:

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/src/rtl8814AU-4.3.21’: File 
exists
fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8814AU-4.3.21
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814AU: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic 
(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log for more 
information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814AU: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic 
(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log for more 
information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

When I look at the log file, I see the same error that I saw from the original driver, which is:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8814AU-4.3.21 for kernel 4.15.0-32-generic 
(x86_64)
Thu Aug 23 12:51:17 PDT 2018
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-32-            
generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from     
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h:41:0,
from 
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/drv_types.h:
from 
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In         
function ‘_init_timer’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/
osdep_service_linux.h:273:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ 
has no member named ‘data’
ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
    ^~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include
/osdep_service_linux.h:274:2: error: implicit declaration of function 
‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function- 
declaration]
init_timer(ptimer);
^~~~~~~~~~
_init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target     
****'/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] 
Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target 
'_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic'
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I am fairly new to ubuntu, and I don't really know what is going on. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the driver file cloned somewhere on your computer? Downloads, perhaps? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: [Get this driver](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au) should work for you. Also see this question [more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968342/dkms-drivers-for-rtl8812au-rtl8814au-network-dongles-fail-to-build-on-17-10-k)

Comment: Awesome! zebulon2's driver worked. Thanks!

Comment: so this solution worked for a while, and then one day it stopped working. I didnt install any major updates, but it just won't work anymore. It says the driver is still installed. Any suggestions?