# Asus USB-AC68 [0b05:1817] on Kernel 4.10, latest Ubuntu Zesty Zapus

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, asus

I'm here for using my Asus USB AC-68, and you're going to tell me this is a duplicate of [Asus USB-AC68 [0b05:1817] drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879187/asus-usb-ac68-0b051817-drivers) but it's not, because both the tutorials from both the answers return a usb that can see wifis, but cannot connect to them.

I keep getting a popup asking me to input the wifi password again, and I'm sure it is good because my built-in card can connect to it with the same password I type. I use Ubuntu Zesty Zapus 17.04 which is on the latest linux 4.10 kernel but it looks like this may impact the usability of my USB.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that can help you
https://www.howtogeek.com/233159/how-to-find-your-wi-fi-password/
first find your password on the back of the adapter
if you previously have it on windows goto
How to Find the Current Wi-Fi Network’s Password on Windows